# Python switch between users

Tags: python, path, switch-statement

I am trying to implement a switch at the beginning of my code, in order to change the working directory based on who's running the code. In Stata, this exists and looks like the following:

```
if "`c(username)'" == "albert" { 
    local PATH "/home/albert/Dropbox/Project1"
} 
else if "`c(username)'" == "charlene" {
    local PATH "C:/Users/charlene/Documents/Dropbox/Project1"
}
```

I am just missing the "user" part in python. Does anyone knows if that even exists ?

Comment: Use a `dict` mapping usernames to paths, i.e. `{"albert": "/home/albert/Dropbox/Project1", ...}`

Comment: But also, what exactly are you using this for? Is this supposed to be a directory relative to the current user's home? For this, there's be better ways than a pseudo-switch.

Comment: Python has if, elif, else statements, if that is what you are wondering...

Comment: @tobias_k yes, this would be used to run my code without having to change the working directory between users.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes I know, thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the [`getpass.getuser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser) function do the trick?